# What do I need to be concerned about when choosing an inkjet printer for edible ink printing?

Tags: printing, edible-ink-printing

I'm going to buy an inkjet printer for [edible ink printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edible_ink_printing).  With an edible ink printer, you basically use ink cartridges filled with food coloring to print on frosting sheets.

I don't want specific model recommendations, but I could use some help in figuring out what to look at.  I'm specifically looking for expertise from people who have done edible ink printing, and I want to know whether printing on frosting sheets imposes the same kinds of limitations as printing on plain paper (vs. photo paper), if the edible printing causes more wear & tear on the printer than normal printing, etc.  In short, I want to know whether it's worth shopping around for a "good" printer for edible ink printing, or if it won't matter because of technical limitations or because I'll be replacing it frequently due to wear & tear or for food safety reasons (one edible ink vendor suggests that 8 months is the average useful lifespan of an inkjet printer used for this purpose).

Are any of the usual specs (resolution, droplet size, sleep settings, etc.) more important or less important than if I was buying the printer for normal photo printing?  For example, I know you need special paper for high-quality, high-resolution photo printing with normal (non-edible) ink.  Do the frosting sheet prints benefit from a higher-resolution printer, or is there some practical limit at which you won't notice any improvement in print quality with edible printing (for example, 1200x1200)?